# Multi Conditional PHP IF statement only if variable has value

Tags: php, if-statement

I have the following if statement, I want to return TRUE if example = sidebar, date start < now, and date end > now. It works as is but the problem is if one of the values doesn't exist, the statement is false.

How can I change the statement to only add conditions if each variable ($position,$date_start, $date_end) isset ? If one of the variables is not set, that portion the condition will be ignored.
For example, if there was no date_end, it would only evaluate for position and date_start

```
<?php 
if ($position == "sidebar" && 
    $date_start < strtotime('now') && 
    $date_end > strtotime('now')): 
?>
```

Comment: If a variable is not set it should ignore that condition. For example if there is no "date_end" it would ignore $date_end > strtotime('now')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to check if each variable is not set OR if it equals the desired value

```
<?php if (
    (!isset($position) || $position == "sidebar") && 
    (!isset($date_start) || $date_start < strtotime('now')) && 
    (!isset($date_end) || $date_end > strtotime('now'))
 ): ?>
```

If you want to allow unset, `null`, `''` (empty string), and `0` values in addition to the specified string values, then you can check `empty()` instead of `isset()`

```
<?php if (
    (!empty($position) || $position == "sidebar") && 
    (!empty($date_start) || $date_start < strtotime('now')) && 
    (!empty($date_end) || $date_end > strtotime('now'))
 ): ?>
```

Comment: This is returning false for the entire statement if any value missing.

Comment: @Sam You're going to need to show the actual code that you're using to produce that, because that wouldn't be the expected result of this.

Comment: How would you expect it to return with the following:
$position = sidebar
$date_start = 11/11/2011
$date_end = (null)

Comment: @Sam See [HERE](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/99b8680b0ddd1d4962a3e36b868cd7ebc8a06d20) as proof that having none of them set will return true.

Comment: @Sam Updated to include another option depending on how your variables are or aren't being "set".